# PHPMyAdmin Getting a Table from a Website SQL

Tags: sql, web-scraping, phpmyadmin

I am trying to get a table from a public website into my phpMyAdmin using SQL.
The website is located here:
https://fulltime.thefa.com/index.html?selectedSeason=259881312&selectedFixtureGroupAgeGroup=0&selectedDivision=882286624&selectedCompetition=0

I assumed it would be a simple:

```
SELECT * FROM "https://fulltime.thefa.com/table.html?league=92031743&selectedSeason=259881312&selectedDivision=882286624&selectedCompetition=0&selectedFixtureGroupKey=1_765438945"
```

But doesnt work and i get the following error (see below screenshot).
Can anyone help?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzJhe.png)

Comment: you need to download the code and format is as data and use the `INSERT` command. you cannot treat an external website as a table in your database. download it as csv or something like that and use the import function in PhpMyAdmin